# there are two object on view both are overlapping each other but event not occurs in phaser 3 javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, overlap, phaser-framework

What I want is when the player overlaps with the coin, the coin disappears, but its not for some reason and I don't why the `cutcoin` function is not called.

```
function create() {
    var  healthGroup = this.physics.add.staticGroup({
      key: 'ycoin',
      frameQuantity: 10,
      immovable: true
    });
    
    var children = healthGroup.getChildren();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
      var x = Phaser.Math.Between(50, 750);
      var y = Phaser.Math.Between(50, 550);
      children[i].setPosition(x, y);
    }

    healthGroup.refresh();
    moveCoin = this.add.sprite(60, 340, "ycoin").setInteractive();
  
    this.input.keyboard.on('keydown-A', () => {   
      moveCoin.allname = "green"
      diceNumber = 1
      moveCoinStep()
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.physics.add.overlap(moveCoin,healthGroup, 
          cutcoin,null,this)
      }, 1000);
    })
}

function cutcoin(movecoin1, healthGroup) {
  console.log('++++++', moveCoin, healthGroup)     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add this line

```
this.physics.add.overlap(moveCoin,healthGroup,cutcoin,null,this)
```

inside keyboard event or on timeout. overlap function is only triggered when overlap occur not on definition. so write the add overlap line outside the keyboard event.
And check the console for any error.